# Conditional probability distribution notation versus conditional probabilities of a single sample space?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

When writing conditional marginal probabilities, the following seems to be the notation:

$$p_{i|Y=y_{j}} = P(X=x_{i}|Y=y_{j}) = \frac{P(X=x_{i},Y=y_{j})}{P(Y=y_{j})}=\frac{p_{ij}}{p_{+j}}$$

This is all well and good; however, doesn't $P(X=x_{i},Y=y_{j})$ simply mean the probability of joint $X$ and $Y$ distributions for given $i$ and $j$ values in each distribution, so would this not simply be the same as intersection, such as $P(X=x_{i}\cap Y=y_{j})$ or something similar? In essence, it seems to me that conditional probability distributions are computed somewhat similar to any conditional set of values within a single distribution.

From my understanding, the joining of two domains in the joint distribution simply expands the sample space, such as considering suits vs card values in a pack of cards, as opposed to just the numbers in the cards. In here, considering suits expands the sample space by 4x to 52 from the 13 possible values of the cards. Then one might say given hearts, what is the probability of choosing a 3 (i.e., $p(3|H)$) is just limiting the sample space to one of four possibilities (the marginal distribution of suits) along one joint domain, and then pursuing the desired calculation.

Is this not the same as treating the sample space as a joint distribution? To me it seems to be in every respect. In that case, why not use the intersection notation ("$A\cap B$") that's standard for the single sample space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\mathsf P(X=x_i, Y=y_j)$ is taken as equivalent to $\mathsf P(X=x_i \cap Y=y_j)$.  It's easier to write and read lists with commas than lots of $\cap$ symbols so we *often* use them for lists of conjunctions.  (Not *always*, but often.)

More specifically it should be something like: $\mathsf P(\{\omega: X(\omega)=x_i\} \cap \{\omega: Y(\omega)=y_j\})$ , the probability of the intersections of sets of outcomes whose $X$ and $Y$ measures equal values $x_i$ and $y_j$ respectively.  But that gets *way too* cumbersome to keep writing so we accept short hand notations for convenience.

**tl;dr** Mathematicians are lazy, okay?